# Kendo UI Mobile Button

Tags: android, listview, button, kendo-ui, listviewitem

I'm trying to use kendo ui mobile framework with on my mobile app. I have to create button dynamically in listview and buttons on click function also.

if i write in html body everything is ok and button behaves normally with click function.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" id="genericListView">
   <li>
        <input type="text">sample
             <a data-align="right" data-role="button" data-click="browse" id="browse"></a>
        </input>
   </li>
</ul>
```

but if i write like below:

```
$('#genericListView').append('<li id="' + result[i].ListItemID + '"><input name="' + result[i].ListItemElementText + '"type="' + result[i].ListItemElementType + 
                        '" id="' + result[i].ListItemElementID + '">' + result[i].ListItemElementText + '<a data-align="left" data-role="button" id="' + result[i].ListItemElementBrowsableID + 
                        '" data-click="' + funcName + '"></a></input></li>');
```

button seems like label on screen and of course click function is not working.

I also tried to add button with

1.input and button tag (not working)

1. creating button with document.createElement and also tried to setAttribute (not working)
2. $('ul').listview('refresh'); (after append, not working)
3. .trigger('create'); (after append, not working)

   I think it's bug on android css (in kendoui mobile framework) because it's working on iOS devices correctly. Any ideas how to fix this problem? or am i miss something?

Comment: An input element cannot have children. Validate your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

```
$('#' + result[i].ListItemElementBrowsableID).kendoMobileButton({ 
                                click: function (event) {
                                    alert('foo');
                                }
                            });
```

if you use kendoMobileButton option anchor button can seems like a button and can behave when the user press the button and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852980/kendo-ui-mobile-trouble-calling-function-on-button-click?rq=1) is the same solution.